# How to capture the inputstream while executing cmd through java?

Tags: java, cmd, inputstream, runas

I have return a small java code to execute the SC command on Remote Server and I am using LSRunas to give the admin credentials.

```
   String[] command = new String [3];
   command[0] = 'cmd';
   command[1] = "/c";
   command[2] = "lsrunas /user:username /password:password /domain:domain /command:"sc \\servername queryex"  /runpath:c\\"


  ProcessBulder buider = new ProcessBuilder(command);
  Process p = buider.start();

   BufferedReader reader = new  BufferedReader(new(InputStreamReader(p.getInputStrem()));
   String line = reader.readLine();
    while(line != null) {
         System.out.println(line);
         line = reader.readLine(); 

    }
```

The program works fine and it execute the SC command with provided credentials on remote server, but the problem is that it opens a new cmd windows to print the result (The common scenario while using RUNAS), But i want to capture the result and read it in my java program. Is there is any way i can capture the result from newly opened cmd window.

Comment: I guess the simplest would be to redirect output to a file and then read it in Java.

Comment: Could you run `larunas` without `cmd`?

Comment: Use while( (line=reader.readLine())!=null) instead for the loop to work

Comment: Hi  @mazaneicha, i tried using the redirect output to a file but it doesn't work . The file gets created but without the content. Thanks

Comment: Hi @NamshubWriter, no i cant use the lsrunas without cmd, Thanks

Comment: To be fully robust you should consume standard input and standard error on separate threads... Read http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html

Comment: Hi @Adam , thanks for the suggestion. I tried that but its of no use. The problem is that the RUNAS command is opening a new window and my process (in java code) is not aware of that. Is there any way in cmd to specify to perform operations in the same window?

Answer (score 0):

```
String line = reader.readLine();
while(line != null) {
     System.out.println(line);
}
```

This will just keep printing out the same line. Try:

```
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: Hi EJP, thanks for the answer but i am using the same thing, but i guess while posting the question i missed that somehow